# HTML embed PDF not work in mobile Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, embed

I want to show PDF files on my website.

This is my code which works perfectly in the normal setting of Chrome

```
<html>
<object data="http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="1000" height="1000">
  <embed src="http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
</html>
```

but not work in mobile setting in Chrome's Toogle device toolbar (see picture below)

[Chrome's Toogle device toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPfLV.png)

Will it be a bug in Chrome or something else?
Please help me thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you have to have the Chrome plug in to view a pdf. Use this code.

```html
<div id="content">
<object data="http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf" width="100%" height="700px"> 
  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.</p>
  <p id="missing-pdf-plugin">You can <a href="http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file</a>.</p>
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $.browser.mozilla) { // firefox
        var msg = "You can <ul><li>either install a PDF plugin such as <a href='https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/'>this one</a> and refresh this page,</li><li>or <a href='http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf'>click here to download PDF file</a>.</li></ul>";
        $("#missing-pdf-plugin").html(msg);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: maybe I have the answer ...  Chrome have to install an extension called pdf viewer